# How do I have an instead function apply for only a specified amount of turns?

Tags: inform7

I am new to inform 7, and I want to undo an instead command that I only wanted to apply earlier. How do I do so? (I want this to happen after an event, using an after statement.)

Comment: I don't quite follow your question. What do you mean by "undoing" an instead rule?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have a little story with an *instead*-rule.

```
"Lasers" by Lynn

The Lab is a room. "To the east lies the vault. If only there weren't
    deadly lasers separating you from it."

The Vault is east from the Lab. "You made it!"
```

```
Instead of going east from the Lab:
    say "A lattice of red-hot laser beams blocks your path."
```

We'd like to "disable" this *instead*-rule once a certain action happens. This can happen from inside an *after*-rule, as you suggest, but also in any other kind of rule.

We could add something like this:

```
Lasers safe is a truth state that varies.

The dial is a device in the Lab. It is fixed in place and switched on.
Carry out switching off the dial: now lasers safe is true.
After switching off the dial: say "The lasers cool down and turn harmless."
```

And now, instead of actually undoing our *instead*-rule definition at run-time, we narrow the condition of its definition down so that it is "defused", never to apply again, once `lasers safe` becomes true.

So we reprogram the instead-rule to read:

```
Instead of going east from the Lab when lasers safe is false:
    say "A lattice of red-hot laser beams blocks your path."
```

Once nice thing about this pparoach is that we can now even "redo" our "undo": a simple `now lasers safe is false` returns the *instead*-rule's old behavior.

---

This solution is generic: you can always define a global truth-value that disables an *instead*-rule like this.

Of course, it is even easier to simply write some thing like:

- `Instead of [action] when the [noun] is (not) [adjective]:`
- `Instead of [action] when we have (not) [verb]ed the [noun]:`

In our case, we are free to write:

```
Instead of going east from the Lab when the dial is switched on:
    say "A lattice of red-hot laser beams blocks your path."
```

or something like:

```
Instead of going east from the Lab when we have not pushed the red button:
    say "..."
```

See [§9.12. Actions as conditions](http://inform7.com/book/WI_9_12.html).